# Access json Data from SAP ODATA via JavaScript/ VueJS

Tags: javascript, database, vue.js, sap-basis

I want to obtain .json Data from my SAP Backend and work with it within my VueJS Project.
There's a link to my JSON data:

> http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/...?$format=json

I have to login with username and password before I can see and/ or download the .json file.

In my VueJS project I want to authenticate automatically, e.g. as it works with Google Firebase, and have access to all the data.

Is there a possibility to accomplish that?

Thank you in advance!!

Comment: And provides you the SAP Backend authentication API as Firebase do?

Comment: I guess? Firebase is just an example of how i guess database authentication can be accomplished.

Comment: So, you must find out how to authenticate with this SAP Backend first. As with Firebase, you need complete the registration to obtain API key first.

Comment: Any ideas where I can find the API keys and how i implement them in my website?

Comment: Just read documentation for your SAP Backend. Not for Firebase, Firebase have nothing to do with SAP.